# Can TypeScript be used in conjunction with PhoneGap (or similar)?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, typescript

So I just learned about TypeScript - hurrah! I'm so happy I can finally join the HTML5 party. My Object Oriented brain is just not compatible with JavaScript ...

However, I immediately wondered if TypeScript actually helps people like me. Sure, I can write JavaScript compatible software with a nice C# style syntax with interfaces & classes, but can it actually be used on anything other than browser apps?

What I'm asking is, can a TypeScript generated JavaScript library be used to create cross-platform mobile apps, say with PhoneGap (or similar framework)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course.

Typescript generates 100% ordinary Javascript; you can use its output anywhere.

Comment: That's cool - are there any examples of this? I'm a bit green when it comes to Javascript. I want to create a Javascript control library then export it across mobile platforms via the HTML5 route.

Comment: @Dr.ABT: See http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/ .  http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ has several examples for how typescript code is translated into javascript code.  Typescript is basically just a superset of javascript, with any typescript-specific features being compiled into plain javascript.  Type-safety functionality is used to protect you from erroneous code, but is not actually included in the javascript output files for typescript code.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is fantastic news. I will endeavour to create a proof of concept :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can get the type definition file for PhoneGap from here:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

or here:

https://github.com/intellifactory/TypedPhoneGap

Answer (score 5):

What DefinitelyTyped currently has for PhoneGap bindings is a good start. I just started a project to push the quality of the bindings a bit further (and eventually perhaps merge into DefinitelyTyped):

1. https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/typedphonegap
2. https://github.com/intellifactory/TypedPhoneGap